# Arrange line plot by order of the variables in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two Phosphorus datasets of two different days of measurement within one depth range and although I have tried to reorder this variable according to depth, R keeps plotting one of the lines in an incorrect order. How can I make this plot show the variation as it occurs?

I am adding an example of the data, the code I used, and a picture of the wrong plot to help to understand.

```
ggplot(dataset_lago, mapping= aes(x = P_Total, y= Depth))+
  geom_line(aes(P_Total, group=day, colour=day))+
  scale_y_reverse()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle("")+
  xlab("P_Total") +
  ylab("Depth") +
  theme_minimal()
```

P_Total -> phosphorus

---

Dataset

| Depth | P_Total | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 401.27 | 26_05_11 |
| 2 | 206.24 | 26_05_11 |
| 4,8 | 163.79 | 26_05_11 |
| 0 | 255.92 | 12_01_12 |
| 2 | 167.72 | 12_01_12 |
| 5 | 300.29 | 12_01_12 |

Thanks in advance for any help.

Wrong Plot

[image: Wrong Plot]

Comment: Could you specify which line is not correct? And is `Prof` variable same with `Depth`?

Comment: In the image added, the red line is not correct. It should appear as the blue one, which shows phosphorus variation along with the depth. And Prof is the same as Depth, I´m correcting it in the question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_path`, this will sort by occurrence in your data frame.

I'd advise keep dates actually stored as dates. The problem is that your factor/character order is defined by the day. By converting this into dates, and converting this into a character with `as.character(lubridate::dmy(day))`, the order will be "correct".

```r
# devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
dataset_lago <- read.so::read_md("| Depth     | P_Total        | day |
| -------- | -------------- | --------------  | 
| 0    | 401.27    | 26_05_11 |
| 2    | 206.24    | 26_05_11 |
| 4.8   | 163.79    | 26_05_11 |        
| 0     | 255.92    | 12_01_12 |                
| 2     | 167.72    | 12_01_12|
| 5     | 300.29    | 12_01_12 | ")

dataset_lago %>%
  mutate(day = dmy(day)) %>%
ggplot(mapping= aes(x = P_Total, y= Depth))+
  geom_path(aes(P_Total, colour= as.character(day)))+
  scale_y_reverse()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "P_Total", y = "Depth") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I run the code exactly as posted above and R is still returning the same previous plot but with "new_day" instead of the dates. 

I installed and loaded the needed packages so I don´t understand what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I used the exact same code but still not working : / 

Is there another way to inform R that it must follow Depth sequency to plot phosphorus?

Comment: ah. I think I understand what you mean, finally. You're not referring to the order of the colors.

Comment: Yes! That´s what I needed. Thank you!